# Bash autocompletion does not fill out names of Java classes in the current directory

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I am using Linux command line to execute my java code. Thus, I used `java`command to execute .class file. But What makes me confused is that autocompletion using the tab key does not extend to the names of classes (which need to be given without extensions).

That is to say, if I'm in a directory with `HelloWorld.java` and `HelloWorld.class`, and I type `java H` and press the `tab` key, I intend the command to be replaced with `java HelloWorld`.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: This is really a feature request more than it is a software-development question. And btw, the word is "complete", not "complement".

Comment: What you describe works for me.  If there is a HelloWorld.class (declared in the root package) in the current directory, typing `java H` followed by pressing tab will result in `java HelloWorld`.  My bash version is 4.4.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run java from bash you need to do the following

```
java -cp <classpath> com.package1.package2.MyClass
```

If your question is why when you click tab bash suggests something like

```
java -cp <classpath> MyClass.class
```

Then this is because to start java you need to provide **full class name** not filename. And bash suggests existing filenames, it knows nothing about java classes and how they are mapped to files.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question confused you. Now I give you my case. There are HelloWorld.java and HelloWorld.class file. To execute the HelloWorld.class by java command, just using`java HelloWorld` command. My question is HelloWorld can not be  automation complement by enter tab key after I enter `java H`. I can make sure that my working directory only have this test file. So there is not a filename conflict.

Comment: @Melvin, yes, but it wouldn't make sense to teach bash to complete filenames in that context, because in many times the class names that are entered *don't* correspond to filenames in the current directory (they could just be coming from jars in the CLASSPATH, after all, and not files directly on-disk at all). I suppose one *could* write an autocompletion handler that searches the classpath locations and knows how to unpack jars, but that's a lot of work for not much benefit. If you want to do that work, nothing's stopping you from writing a PR for https://github.com/scop/bash-completion

Comment: (In addition to being a fair bit of work, one would need to cache lookup results to get reasonable performance, and clear that cache when the CLASSPATH changes).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add `.class` when you run `java User.class`: just run `java User`.